# .NET Beans + request scope - is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have my web application. I need, when a user do a request (I mean, call a page) create an object that store some information (it get these from database) for each request (so the data is updated at every request) and for each user (so UserA don't share the same object regard UserB).

I use to work on Java and some Web Frameworks (like Struts, Spring and JSF) and there was possible to create these objects (JavaBeans) with scope of request, and putting them visible for the whole application. I mean :

```
public class iContext
{
    public iContext()
    {
        Response.Write(myBeans.Title());
    }    
}
```

it's possible without create an Istance of MyBeans every time .
I thought to put the object on session, but I prefeer to get rid about this (in fact I should check, replace, delete or insert the object every time and done tons of queries :)).

Are there some strategies to do this kind of work on .NET 3.5 and C#?

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "for each request *and for each user*". Is it possible that *the same request* involves *more than one user*?

Comment: @Heinzi : I mean that object must be unique for each request :) (so, for each user). Sorry!

Comment: If you were using ASP.NET MVC, I'd say use ModelBinding and send strongly typed objects in your requests.  In Webforms, it's a little more painful because they abstract away the web; but you could use ViewState.

Comment: @George Stocker : can you give an example please?

Comment: @markzzz: In Webforms, a new request is created on each postback. Do you need the value to persist across postbacks?

Comment: No, I need to get the value from database each time....

Comment: Ok, then HttpContext indeed sounds like the easiest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.Net it's important to know the page's [life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#additional_page_life_cycle_considerations). If you understand this, you could use the HttpContext.Items[] Dictionary object to fill with your custom context class in the (pre) init phase of the page. Anywhere you load data that's important to keep in memory you can add it to your context class and use it anywhere you want since HttpContext is available at all times in the scope of your page.

Comment: Would nice to know how this Class works! In fact is what I need to understand/learn; thanks for the tip, I'll try to search informations...

Comment: But this HttpContext.Items[] is sharable for every user on the web app? Or each user will have his own HttpContext.Items[]? (Is what I need)

Comment: Tried `HttpContext.Current.Items["page"] = myObject;`. Seems to be stored. The only problem is that I need to use `protected MyObject myObject= (MyObject)(HttpContext.Current.Items["page"]);` every time I need to use that object, and this is annoying :)

Comment: Ok, resolved with `HttpContext.Current.Items`. In fact I really don't know how it could work : if it's visible to the whole application, should be "static". But in fact is not static...

Comment: @markzzz: HttpContext.Current *is* static: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx