# Is it possible to extend 2 classes at once?

Tags: c#, .net

I have these classes :

```
public class myClassPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public myClassPage ()
    {
    
    }
}

public class myClassControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public myClassControl ()
    {
    
    }
}
```

and I'd like have another Class that extends these classes, something like this :

```
public class myClassData : myClassPage, myClassControl
{
    public myClassData ()
    {
    
    }
}
```

is it possible to do this or is there something else I could do?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: See: [Why doesn't C# support multiple inheritance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-doesn-t-c-support-multiple-inheritance.aspx)

Comment: @SLaks♦ : I need to share an object for my whole web application. So if each class (page) extends these classes, i can share the reference to that object...

Comment: @markzzz can you not use a static property?

Comment: Yes, I can't use static property :)

Comment: @markzzz: Inheritance is *not* a suitable means for sharing references to the same object. What are you trying to do?

Comment: this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664097/net-beans-request-scope-is-it-possible

Comment: @markzzz - what is the reason that you cannot use a static property? Please elaborate in your question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the case where you need to extend two classes, you might be served to favor composition over inheritance, and to use interfaces as other answers have mentioned. An example:

Start by definining your interfaces

```
interface IFoo 
{
    void A(); 
}

interface IBar
{
    void B();
}
```

Then create concrete classes that implement each interface

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void A()
    {
         // code
    }
}

class Bar : IBar 
{
    public void B()
    {
         // code 
    }
}
```

Finally, in the class you want to exhibit both sets of behaviors, you can implement each interface but compose the implementations with the concrete classes.

```
public class Baz : IFoo, IBar
{
    IFoo foo = new Foo(); // or inject 
    IBar bar = new Bar(); // or inject

    public void A()
    {
        foo.A();
    }

    public void B()
    {
        bar.B();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

This is called Multiple Inheritance. You can find more information on [Wikipedia - Multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) regarding the subject.

Multiple inheritance is supported in some langages:

> Languages that support multiple inheritance include: C++, Common Lisp, Curl, Dylan, Eiffel, Logtalk, Object REXX, Scala, OCaml, Perl, Perl 6, POP-11, Python, and Tcl

In C#, interfaces can be used for mimicking multiple inheritance:

> Some object-oriented languages, such as **C#**, Java, and Ruby implement single inheritance, although interfaces provide some of the functionality of true multiple inheritance.

Example:

```
public class myClassData : myClassPageInterface, myClassControlInterface 
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Example: `public class myClassData : myClassPageInterface, myClassControlInterface { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to inherit multiple base classes in C#.  You are able to implement two interfaces, or follow some workarounds (though this should be done with caution).

Links:

- [SO: Multiple Inheritence in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c): Discussion of MI methods and a good description of "composition".
- [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/smip.aspx): An example of a workaround
- [C-SharpCorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cbreakspear/MultipleInheritance11082005004843AM/MultipleInheritance.aspx): Some alternatives to multiple inheritence

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible, but look at this link.

[Simulated Multiple Inheritance Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/smip.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

use interface

in c# class Multiple  inheritance not support

also refer

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance