# How to extend two classes from one class(mvvmcross)

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am developing one android application on xamarin, I am facing some issues regarding extending classes, I have one button in fragment and on click I want to logout user for that I have to extend one another class, so that for work I am extending fragment and for logout I want to extend BaseAccountView...
So please if anyone having any idea then told***

*** - we are using MVVMCROSS plarform

Answer (score 1):

You can not inherit multiple classes directly in CSharp - that's what abstractions are for. I'd strongly recommend learning fundamentals of the language before jumping into Xamarin - you're likely to find issues in the future which could easily be avoided with some preparation.

PluralSight has some great courses, as well as Channel9

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to do multiple inheritance, which is not supported in C#. I would try and simplify it.
There are couple of really helpful links for that

[Is it possible to extends 2 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664974/is-it-possible-to-extends-2-classes)

[Multiple Inheritance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp)